# Please clarify gRPC cancel semantics

Tags: grpc

Am I right in assuming the following semantics for cancelling a call (unary or streaming) from the client side will result in:

- the client will just cancel the request on the transport level
- the client will not wait for any ACK from the server to confirm cancellation (non-blocking cancel)
- hence, it could still be that the server is continuing with the execution of the request

If that’s true is there any blocking version of cancel?

Comment: what client and server language are you using? At least for Golang the server side can ask the context if it is canceled/deadline exceeded and then stop working. But its a deliberate decision.

Comment: Of course, the server can check the flag, but what I am looking for are the CLIENT side semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's all true.

There is no version of cancel that would block until it received acknowledgement from the service-side application that it is no longer processing the RPC. (There is no version of cancel that blocks for any reason.)